# Selecting features by radius using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

in QGIS there's a very useful tool "Select features by radius", I'd like to add a similar function in my plugin. The user should be able to choose the radius and the center of the circle (from a chosen feature).

Is there a way to call "Select features by radius" using PyQGIS?

I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to artwork21 and Ben W advices, I've written this code. Probably there's a better way to do the same thing, but it seems to work.

```
#userFeature is user input
#userDistance is user input

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('myLayer')[0]
it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( QgsExpression("id = '"+userFeature+"'") ) )
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
layer.selectByIds(ids) 

selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feat in selection:
    geom = feat.geometry()
    buff = geom.buffer(userDistance,5)

intersectedFeaturesList=[]

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    if feature.geometry().intersects(buff):
        intersectedFeaturesList.append(str(feature.attributes()[0])) #attributes()[0] are the ids in my layer

seperator = ', '
rowsString=seperator.join(intersectedFeaturesList)
expr = QgsExpression( "id in ("+rowsString+")")

it=layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
layer.selectByIds(ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the select feature by radius method but you could create a plugin where the user defines a selection point on the map which then in the back-end creates an in-memory buffered polygon (by x distance, distance sourced from a textbox widget in a Qt form) which selects any feature(s) that intersect the buffer layer.

Comment: It's a good idea, I'll try in this way. Thanks

Comment: Hi spent my all afternoon looking for buffer usins PyQGIS. I didn't find versions compatible with qgis 3. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Lorenzo, `buffer()` is a method of the `QgsGeometry` class. See the docs here: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ab7302c054a2c5514222b4bd71df71ab8.